# How to make div filled with browser window

Tags: css, html, css-float

After visiting many sites on the internet, I could not find the way, How can I make a `div` which fills the browser window? Firstly it should be hidden but on postback, it should be visible. This div is not the direct child of the `body` tag instead it is placed inside the table row. What kind of CSS should I apply so that it will positioned to fit the window? I Used below `Css` for `div` but doesn't work for me.

```css
.BodyCover { 
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

**EDIT**

and HTML markup is below,

```html
<table>
   <tr>
      <td>Content</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>Content</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td><div class="BodyCover "></div></td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

How can I achieve this either way means I want to have DIV like floating on the body event some button clicks. How can this be possible in another way?

Comment: Why on earth would you cover 100% your window with an element that is inside `table`? put is a first or last descendant of `body`.

Answer (score 0):

percent based width and height are relative to the wrapping element (so is position absolute by the way), so if you want your div to cover the whole body you have no choice but to make it a direct descendent of the body, OR use javascript to manually change the size and position of the div.

the interesting question is why you want a div to be a part of a table but cover the whole screen...

Answer (score 0):

Try this, worked for me:

```css
.BodyCover { 
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
}​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/jeL3D/

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with;

```
body{
   height:100%;
   margin:0;
}

.full{
    display:block;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    background:#F00;
    position:absolute;
    visibility:hidden;
}
<table border="1">
    <tr>
        <td id="rw"><div class="full" id="dv">text here</div>click</td>
        <td><div>text1</div></td>
    </tr>
    
    <tr>
        <td><div>text2</div></td>
        <td><div>text3</div></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/MvtYU/19/

Comment: My DIV is in the table row

Comment: (body...) ok margin, ... but why `padding:0;` ? Does `body` has some default padding to be afraid of?

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan yes you're right. it's unnecessary.re-edit it.thanks for your comment

Answer (score 0):

You can now use viewport height and viewport width - vh and vw respectively. 
100vh, for example, fills the height of the viewport window.